# Indexing and searching with sphinx for words with signs like (++, #, .)

Tags: sphinx

Hi I have build an index and I need to search for words like "c++", ".net" or "c#", but
there is not an result coming. Here is my config:

```
source = xxxx
path = /usr/local/etc/sphinx/var/data/xxxx
docinfo = extern
charset_type = utf-8
min_word_len = 1
min_infix_len = 7
stopwords = /usr/local/etc/sphinx/var/stopwords/stop_words_en.txt
```

I have try to search with SPH_MATCH_PHRASE and SPH_MATCH_ALL, but there is nothing useful coming.

What can I do to allow this?

Thanks
Nik

Answer (score 1):

You have to configure **charset_table** to include symbols **+, #, .,**

ie

```
index YOUR_INDEX
{
charset_table = 0..9, A..Z->a..z, a..z, +, #, U+002E,
```

You could check how words get tokenized via CALL KEYWORDS MySQL call

with config you provided I'd get such output

mysql> CALL KEYWORDS ('c++ .net c# end_of_a_sentence.', 'YOUR_INDEX')

tokenized normalized
c         c
net       net
c         c
end       end 
of        of
a         a
sentence  sentence

with my addition to your config the output is
tokenized normalized
c++         c++
.net       .net
c#         c#
end        end
of         of
a          a
sentence.  sentence.

The downside of the **dot (.)** in **charset_table** that word at the end of a sentence tokenized and indexed together with a **dot**

**'The example sentence.'**

The **'sentence'** word would be tokenized as a **'sentence.'** and searching for the **'sentence'** gives you nothing.

Answer (score 0):

As [tmg_tt](https://stackoverflow.com/users/673792/tmg-tt) says, modifying the `charset_table` should work.

However, you need to escape the `#` and probably the `+`, in the index definition in `sphinx.conf`:

```
charset_table=0..9, A..Z->a..z, _, a..z,\#, U+A8->U+B8, U+B8, U+C0..U+DF->U+E0..U+FF, U+E0..U+FF
```

Works for pound, but I have not figured out how to escape `+`, at least in `Sphinx 0.99`.

I am posting to the `sphinx` forums about this too.

Comment: recommendation is to use the HEX/Unicode equivalents for the # and +, which would be: U+23, U+2B. Also, if using PHP, urldecode and urlencode must be changed to rawurldecode and rawurlencode or + will not work.